# How to uninstall ubuntu server 14.04 amd64

Tags: uninstall

How to uninstall ubuntu,i can't boot into ubuntu because i forgot my password.I don't have any window live cd,but have window vista and  xp,and have ubuntu server live cd.I have tried with grub loader,but still can't uninstall.Please someone help me.

Comment: you can set the new password to your account http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Answer (score 0):

You can not "uninstall" an operating system, but you can:

- [reset your password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)
- format the partition (you will lose your
  data) and / or install (another) operating system